# How do I get the connection information using vba in ms-access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am going to answer this question myself. I spent some time looking for the connection information to one of my tables for some documentation of one of my databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debug.print method or simply open the immediate window using `Ctrl + g` then use the following code.

```
 debug.? CurrentDB.TableDefs("my_table_name").connect
```

The source of my answer is the following youtube video:
https://youtu.be/soSKpnM4wcg?t=17m42s

Comment: That's the connection info. Not related at all to the table definition.

Comment: My apologies, I have changed the question to better fit the terms of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The question text and the question body both have different meanings.

If you looking to display or print out the table definition, then you can use the Database documenter to display or printout the table definition of given table.

From the ribbon tab “Database Tools”, choose the Database documenter. Select the table(s) you want, and the result is this:

[image]